# How to print a custom user field in comment.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming, entities, hooks, comments

I'm trying to print a custom user field (field_avatar) image as a replacement for the user picture. Why? user picture file directory would not accept tokens. This mean, I could run into a scenario where there are 100k files in a directory slowing the website!

From googling answers for hours, this is the best solution I've read.

In comment.tpl.php placed in my custom omega 4 subtheme, I added this code.

```
<?php  print render(field_view_field('user', $user, 'field_avatar'));  ?>
```

However, above code prints the default field_avatar picture! not field_avatar based on the comment ID? or UID of the author?

Please shed some wisdom smart ones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it working! I've used user_load($comment->uid) to load the author relationship.

I placed the code in a copy of comment.tpl.php in my sub theme.

```
<?php print render(field_view_field('user',user_load($comment->uid), 'YOUR-CUSTOM-USER-FIELD'));?>
```

Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the $author of the comment rather than the currently logged in $user.  Luckily, $author comes as a parameter to the tpl file, try this?:

```
<?php
  print render(field_view_field('user', $author, 'field_avatar'));
?>
```

Comment: I tried it. Cleared the cache and everything. Unfortunately, It's still rendering the default picture. Note: I'm not trying to print the current user of the site, but the author of the comment.

Comment: Oh of course, hang on I'll update the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried   $author and $node to no avail :(. I'm reading comment.module to get some insight.

Comment: perhaps render() doesn't work the same way for $author fields, or the $author object is structured differently to $user.  You can use `dpm($author);` to check the object (make sure devel module is installed first).

Comment: I'll just resort to views for now. >.>

Comment: Have you tried to write something else just to see if your modifying the right template? I think that if you render field_avatar the result will never be user->picture. Also if you want to get the author of the comment just load it from the comment uid property. If you haven't loaded the comment yet then just do it, probably it will be in Drupal's cache anyway so it will not hurt performance.

Comment: @BetoAveiga  Yes, the template is the correct one. It's outputting other changes I put to it. I'll try your suggestion about loading comment UID (which makes sense) after I test ride solr search.

Comment: @Darvanen figured it out! check out my answer :D.

Comment: @BetoAveiga I've implemented what you said and got it working!

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear it!

Comment: Likewise, figured it was something along those lines.